# How to sort a numbered list

Tags: c#, linq

So I have this numbered list that I need to sort numerically:

```
1
1.1.
1.1.1.
1.1.2.
1.1.3.
1.1.4.
1.1.5.
1.1.6.
1.1.7.
1.2.
1.2.1.
1.2.2.
1.2.3.
1.2.4.
1.2.5.
1.2.6.
1.3.
1.3.1.
1.3.2.
1.3.3.
1.3.4.
1.4.
1.4.1.
1.4.2.
1.4.3.
1.5.
1.5.1.
1.5.2.
1.5.3.
1.6.
1.6.1.
1.6.1.1.
1.6.1.2.
1.6.2.
1.6.2.1.
1.6.2.2.
1.6.2.3.
1.6.2.4.
1.6.2.5.
1.6.2.6.
1.6.3.
1.6.3.1.
1.6.3.2.
1.6.3.3.
1.6.3.4.
1.6.3.5.
1.6.4.
1.6.5.
1.7.
1.7.1.
1.7.1.1.
1.7.1.2.
1.7.1.3.
1.7.2.
1.7.3.
1.7.4.
1.7.5.
1.7.5.1.
1.7.5.2.
1.7.6.
1.7.7.
1.7.8.
1.7.9.
1.8.
1.9.
1.10.
```

Issue is when trying to sort 1.10. will come right before 1.2. instead of after 1.9.

Any Idea how I can achieve this using C# or linq?

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to parse them into some kind of tuple or array of integers and sort those.

Comment: Assuming they're strings, split them into components and sort by component.

Comment: First split on period, then parse each to an `int`, then order by the first, then second, and so on.

Comment: Exact, but I need to sort them numerically.

Comment: best way is to sort integers, but if you must deal with strings then rewrite each entry as 2 digit strings such that `1.10` becomes `01.10`, `1.2` becomes `01.02` etc

Comment: `when trying to sort 1.10. will come right before 1.2` that hapens when they are not numbers but strings (numerals).  There are several great posts here on 'Natural Sort' and even how to call/use the one built into Windows

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [`IComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) class to help the sorter do what you want:

```
class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        string[] xParts = x.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] yParts = y.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i = 0;;i++)
        {
            if (xParts.Length >= i && yParts.Length < i)
                return 1;
            if (xParts.Length < i && yParts.Length >= i)
                return -1;
            if (xParts.Length < i && yParts.Length < i)
                return 0;

            int compared = int.Parse(xParts[i]).CompareTo(int.Parse(yParts[i]));
            if (compared != 0)
                return compared;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can sort your values like so:

```
var sorted = values.OrderBy(s => s, new MyComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: That doesn't even compile.  What if `compared` is 0?

Comment: @juharr What doesn't compile about it? It does on my computer. If `compared` is 0 it loops again and checks the next value.

Comment: Not all paths have a return.

Comment: @juharr Did you *try* to compile it? All paths have a return value.

Comment: Did not realize the compiler would be smart enough to figure that out.

Comment: Although this will crash when comparing "1.2." to "1.2.1." since you cannot parse an empty string into an `int`.

Comment: @juharr Thanks, I've edited my answer to address that.

Comment: This will still crash when comparing "1" to "1.5.7".

Comment: @SelimYıldız It shouldn't. When `i` is 1, the `if (xParts.Length < i && yParts.Length >= i)` will evaluate to true and -1 will be returned. What are you seeing that I'm not?

Answer (score -1):

you can use Sort method of the List

```
 List<int> lista = new List<int>() {2,6,1,2,4,9,0,3};
                lista.Sort();

                foreach (var item in lista)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue in the question: There is a collection of strings in the form "1.10.1.", "1.2.1.", etc. OP knows how to perform a default sort. The question is how to make "1.10.1." sort ***after*** "1.2.1."